# Can I make my apps update automatically once a week? (4.1 Jelly Bean)

Tags: applications, updates, 4.3-jelly-bean

I was updating my apps automatically but every time they update my anti-virus would scan the installed app and make the whole system freeze, which is quite annoying. So is there any way to make them all update once a week, let's say, every Sunday morning? Or, is there any app to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the auto update from Play Store settings and update manually every week. Or you could disable the app scanning of your antivirus and instead set a scan of all your apps every week, I think the probability that an app update and the scan to collide will be very low. This way you wouldn't have to do the manual update. Also, you could try some of the Play Store alternatives in this [article,](https://www.androidpit.com/best-google-play-store-alternative-app-stores) but I don't know if they have an update scheduling function.

Comment: My AV will scan the apps as soon as they are installed, that's the problem. But I'll schedule a weekly virus scan and set google play to update automatically as you said. Thanks